# Ubuntu GNOME isn't booting after install

Tags: boot, grub2, gnome, system-installation, uefi

I've installed Ubuntu 2 times but it isn't booting. I've tried to create /boot partition and use boot-repair to solve this but it didn't helped.
After turning on the notebook it opens BIOS and when I open "boot" section there is simply nothing.
But when I boot from Live USB (I've used YUMI to create Linux Mint and Ubuntu GNOME multiboot) and click to "Boot from First Disk" it boots normally. Now I'm writing this from my Ubuntu booted from Live USB but it doesn't boot without live USB. Why? How to solve this?
No other OSs, Ubuntu GNOME is the latest version, reinstalling GRUB2 didn't helped. Thank you.

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.